# How to paint a cut off branch on a spruce tree?

Tags: cuttings, spruces, branches

I have a spruce tree (picea abies), which is next to a path and since one of the lower branches was obstructing the passing down the path, I cut it off.
Now my question is how do I paint the place where the branch was? What kind of paint should I use, is color important, or is there some special substance just for that?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: This could be a duplicate of https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/3666/are-tar-based-products-really-useful-in-treating-tree-wounds, where answer is "anything. But also a duplicate of https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/25236/how-do-i-treat-a-wound-where-a-branch-broke-off-my-apple-tree, where answer is "do not paint on it"... To me, however, the real good answer is another possible duplicate: https://gardening.stackexchange.com/a/13762/14120  well explained with arguments: => **DO NOT PAINT, possibly clean**

Comment: I saw this one - https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/25236/how-do-i-treat-a-wound-where-a-branch-broke-off-my-apple-tree but since it was about treating a broken branch on an apple tree, I didn't think it would apply to my case. However, the other links give me the answer I need, thanks. The only problem is the place is very visible (very bright circle, compared to the very dark bark), so I was thinking of painting it some dark color, but since it's best not to to do that, I won't.

Comment: Take some damn earth and smear it on the cut to help color it.

Comment: @Ben, careful, earth contains numerous pathogens we might not want on the tree.

Comment: @peter_s, the color should fade with time. Maybe black squid ink could do the trick better than earth.

Comment: @peter_s, if you reword your question, asking about coloration only, then I think it wouldn't be a duplicate anymore, and you might get more feedback.